# Dynamically created checkbox id doesn't found

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created Panel inside which there is a table and in turn, inside which i have created checkboxes dynamically.

```
int RoleCount = CountRoles();
string[] RoleName = RoleNames();
CheckBox[] chk = new CheckBox[RoleCount];
Table TableCheckBox = new Table();
TablePanel.Controls.Add(TableCheckBox);

TableRow tRow = new TableRow();

for (int i = 0; i < RoleCount; i++)
{
    chk[i] = new CheckBox();
    chk[i].ID = "chk" + RoleName[i];
    chk[i].Text = RoleName[i];
    chk[i].ClientIDMode = System.Web.UI.ClientIDMode.Static;
    TableCell tCell = new TableCell();
    tCell.Controls.Add(chk[i]);
    if (i != 0 && i % 3 == 0)
    {
        TableCheckBox.Rows.Add(tRow);
        tRow = new TableRow();
    }
    if (i < RoleCount)
        tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);
        TableCheckBox.Rows.Add(tRow);
    }
```

Now, if i want to find this control by the code, then it doesn't work. cb returns null.

```
int RoleCount = CountRoles();
string[] RoleName = RoleNames();

string chkboxbit = " ";

try
{
    foreach (string s in RoleName)
    {
        for (int i = RoleCount-1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            chkboxbit = "chk" + RoleName[i];
            ContentPlaceHolder cph = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");
            Panel panel = (Panel)cph.FindControl("TablePanel");
            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTable table = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTable)panel.FindControl("TableCheckBox");
            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputCheckBox cb = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputCheckBox)table.FindControl(chkboxbit);
            if (cb != null)
                cb.Checked= false;
        }
    }
}
catch
{
    Response.Redirect("Error.aspx");
}
```

What should I do ?

Comment: You have to (re)create all dynamically created controls on every postback, in `Page_Load` at the latest and with the same ID's as before. All objects are disposed at the end of the page's life-cycle. So you only need to persist the information how many controls were already created. I don't know how `CountRoles()` get the number, you can use the `Session` or `ViewState`.

Comment: Hey Tim! cb still returns null.

Comment: Have you used the debugger? The code is a little bit confusing. Why do you have the `if (i < RoleCount)` at all? That is always `true` in the loop. But every third iteration you're adding two `TableRows` to the `Table`, is that desired? Once  in the first `if` and once in the second.

Comment: i m using this condition because i want there shud be only 3 colimns in the tables.

Comment: In what page event your creation code is running? If it not in the Page Init event, try to move your code in it, in that place ViewState not yet applied, so I believe that in the load event or in other later events ViewState will be applied on your dynamically created items to restore their states as your expected

Answer (score 0):

It is done.
Since i'm creating CheckBox type therefore following code is suitable for it, i think so because my code runs properly.

```
ContentPlaceHolder cph = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");
Panel panel = (Panel)cph.FindControl("TablePanel");
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTable table = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTable)panel.FindControl("TableCheckBox");
System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox cb = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox)table.FindControl(chkboxbit);
if (cb != null)
{
    if (cb.Checked == true)
    cb.Checked = false;
}
```